# Why is int pointer able to store string?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I have tried out the following but I'm not able to get the working behind it.

```
char *s;
s="hello";
printf("%s",s);
```

Obviously, this prints hello perfectly. Now, if we use the following code, it also works perfectly.

```
int *s="hello";
printf("%s", s);
```

The output of this is also hello.
And if we do `double *s="hello";`, that also works.
Can anyone help me out with this problem with the proper explanation?

Comment: If your compiler is not shrieking at you, you need to get a better compiler (or, at least, turn on some compiler warnings).  Do *not* ignore compiler warnings.  The compiler knows far more about C than you do — witness this question — and only generates warnings when the problem is serious.  (GCC 5.2.0 and 6.1.0 with no warning options both say: `warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` for the line
`int *s="hello";` — that is an indication of a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It is compiling perfectly. and according to me there will be a proper working of it. we all know that data type of the pointer variable  should be the type of the variable whose address it is storing. so int *s will store the address of variable that is of int type. but it is not so if u do this s="hello". this statement that we need to think about. What is it doing? if we know the answer of it than we can surely understand it working.

Comment: You need a compiler upgrade then.  Which version of which compiler are you using, and on which platform are you using it?  Does the compiler date from the current millennium?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using GCC 4.9.2. and you are correct bro ,it is showing the same warning but at the same time is compiling too. So it means that there is no syntax error. Why is it then compiling? And how int *s;s="hello"  is syntatically correct. And even if we do s=12344; It compiles. What does this line mean then?

Comment: Like I said: the compiler will do its utmost to produce something that might resemble what you intended, but it will give warnings when it thinks you're doing something wrong (even if it produces a program).  If you get a warning with no warning options set, it is very, very important you don't ignore it.  When I'm compiling (code to demonstrate on SO), I routinely use options `gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror -std=c11 -g` (and usually have a few extra warnings enabled).  I don't bother with running the code until it compiles cleanly under those options.

Comment: If you're really lazy at typing and can't bother making an alias, `-Wall` often gives you 90 % of the important ones.

Comment: @GauravChandani the C standard does not define that a compiler **must** reject a program that uses these constructs, so GCC also does not reject them by default, because then there'd be million people saying "But it compiles on MSVC just fine". Use `-Werror`. If you think they're not errors, use `-Werror`.

Comment: And yes, you're correct; syntactically, the program is valid.  It just isn't valid semantically.  You're attempting to do that which leads to undefined behaviour.  One of the possible results of undefined behaviour is that the code behaves as you expect, even though you have no right to expect it to behave like that.  Another possible result is a crash; theoretically, it could reformat your hard disk (if you still have one), or give you an attack of ['nasal demons'](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) (search for it).

Comment: There is no Kind of Pointer which is able to hold something, there is only memory places and there points Pointers. Get a book.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes,now the error is being displayed instead of warning. But I noticed one thing that you can perhaps answer. If we do 'char *s="hello" ' no error ,no warning. Now if we do 'int *s=2345'. warning that turned error after **-Werror**. Why is it so ?

Comment: @Michi pointer stores the address of the memory place and **point through that address**. Given in book Let Us C. Go and read it

Comment: @GauravChandani Read the AnttiHaapal's Answer. If you don't need a book.

Comment: The idea behind the `-Werror` flag is that every warning is treated as if it were an error.  Using it along with `-Wall` means you avoid compiling code with silly little problems.  Adding more options such as `-Wextra` avoids more problems.  If you have the `clang` compiler, it has a `-Weverything` option that is very, very fussy.  It's good discipline to have your code compile cleanly under the most stringent set of warnings you can tolerate.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is getting so many downvotes. There are clearly some things the OP doesn't know -- which is why he's asking about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the string is not stored in a pointer. Instead the pointer points to the beginning of the string. String literals such as `"hello"` are usually located alongside the code in read-only sections of a running process.
Furthermore a `char *` can be *cast* to a `int *` and vice versa with a cast operator:

```
char *foo = "hello";
int *bar = (int*)foo;
foo = (char*)bar;
```

However converting between these pointer types without a cast is not standard-compliant; so given

```
char *foo;
int *bar;
```

neither of these statements

```
foo = bar;
bar = foo;
```

is standard-compliant.

---

Your program is not strictly-conforming; this cannot be done in a standard-compliant way.

C11 draft n1570 *Appendix J.2* states that behaviour is undefined if:

> —  Two  pointer  types  that  are  required  to  be  compatible  are  not  identically  qualified,  or are not pointers to compatible types (6.7.6.1).

And *6.5.4.1 Cast operators* says that

> Conversions  that  involve  pointers,  other  than  where  permitted  by  the  constraints  of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast.

6.5.16.1 then says that without a cast you can do an assignment to a compatible pointer, or that assign a pointer to void to a pointer to object, or assign a pointer to object to a pointer to void.

Now, `int *` and `char *` are not pointers to compatible types, so the behaviour is undefined. Now, undefined behaviour is defined as

> **1 undefined behavior**
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>
> **2 NOTE**
>
> Possible  undefined  behavior  ranges  from  ignoring  the  situation  completely  with  unpredictable
>   results, to ***behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
>   environment  (with  or  without  the  issuance  of  a  diagnostic  message)***,  to  terminating  a  translation  or
>   execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

***(enphasis mine)***.

With default settings, GCC decides to behave in documented manner, issuing a diagnostic message, but not terminating the translation (compilation):

> ```
> test.c:1:8: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type 
>     [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>  int *s = "hello";
>           ^
> ```

One can make warnings into fatal errors with `-Werror` switch, which terminates the translation alongside with issuing a diagnostics message:

> ```
> % gcc test.c -Werror
> test.c:1:8: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type 
>
>     [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
>  int *s = "hello";
>         ^
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> ```

---

Even though when compiling with default settings GCC still successfully compiles your program, your program is not strictly conforming, and thus not maximally portable. Other compilers and future versions of GCC can terminate the translation with default switches, or fail to produce working code.

Answer (score 0):

Because in C there is not strong type casting, you can assign to a pointer whatever data you want. With the `%s` in the `printf()`, you tell the compiler to use the `int` pointer as a pointer to a `char` array, and that works perfectly because you *do* assign a `char` array to the `int` pointer.

Comment: I think you mean strong type *checking*. But in fact `int *s="hello";` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your program  has two serious error, one that a conforming compiler must diagnose, and another that a conforming compiler is not required to diagnose, but that causes undefined behavior at run time.

```
char *s;
s="hello";
printf("%s",s);
```

This is perfectly valid.  You define a pointer to `char` object, `s`, and initialize it to point to the string `"hello"`. You then pass it to `printf`. The `"%s"` format tells `printf` to expect a `char*` pointer that points to a string, and that's exactly what you've passed.

```
int *s="hello";
```

You've defined `s` as a pointer to `int`. And you've attempted to initialize it to point to a string. That's a *constraint violation*, meaning that the compiler must diagnose it, at least with a warning. If you're not getting a warning, then your compiler is non-conforming, and you should find out how to make it work correctly. If you're getting a warning and ignoring it, *don't do that*. Many C compilers (including gcc) issue non-fatal warnings for some constraint violations, particularly those involving pointer conversions. You should pay close attention to compile-time warnings, and you should consider finding out how to make your compiler treat such violations as fatal errors.

gcc's default behavior is to issue the required diagnostic (a warning is permitted; IMHO a fatal error would be better, but it's not required), and then generate code *as if* the initialization caused a conversion from `char*` to `int*`. You definitely should not depend on this behavior. Other compilers might behave differently.

```
printf("%s", s);
```

As I wrote above, the `"%s"` format makes `printf` assume that it will receive a `char*` argument that points to a string. Instead, you've passed an `int*` argument. Because of the special nature of `printf` (it's a *variadic* function, and the number and types of required arguments are specified by the format string, not by `printf` itself), the compiler can't necessarily diagnose the error. For example, the format string could be a variable rather than a string literal.

On many systems, `char*` and `int*` pointers have the same size and representation, and are passed to functions in the same way -- and converting a `char*` to an `int*` yields a pointer with the same representation as if it had been properly defined as a `char*` pointer in the first place. So it can happen that your call "works" the same way as if you had written the code properly. This doesn't mean the code is correct; it means that it has a serious error that isn't showing up in your program's behavior.

It's still your responsibility to write code that follows the rules, even if the compiler can't always enforce those rules, and even if the program *appears* to "work".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I had made the **Werror** mode on in gcc compiler,and now it is showing an error for int *s="hello"; But why is it showing an error for int *s=1234;. This code is same as char *s="hello"(which is error and warnin free). As we are assigning string to char pointer,similarly **why can't we assigning integer to int pointer**. Explain me this behaviour

Comment: It's not the same thing at all. `"hello"` is a string literal which refers to an array object. It "decays" to a pointer to that object's first element. `1234` is an `int` value; there is no object for the pointer to refer to.